# Should I exclude dummy variables that are skewed?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data

I ran a pooled OLS regression for house prices. I have noticed that the variables that have the wrong sign, are those that have a skewed dummy variable

For example, the dummy variable indicating whether a property is furnished or not:

1    N = 25,580    % = 4.39
  0    N = 556,556   % = 95.61

Would it be justified to exclude these dummy variables, or should I include them regardless of this?

Comment: How do you know the signs are wrong, and what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Variables that should increase house prices, have a negative sign. I expect them to be + rather than - , because a massive amount of house price literature has found this to be true. For instance, the dummy variable indicating whether the property is furnished, has a negative sign. I would expect, all else equal, that a furnished property can command a higher rent than a non-furnished property. This also contradicts other dummy variables, like the presence of a TV, washing machine and dryer, which are positive.

Comment: It seems strange to me that skewness would cause this.  Another possibility is that the sign reversals are due to correlations between the predictors, which seems plausible from your comment.  You may want to look at a correlation matrix of the predictors for starters to see what's going on.

Comment: I thought it might be due to the skewness because when I excluded those predictors, and kept furnished, it was still negative. But I did not check directly for correlation, so I will do that now